# Java , how to set up correctly Servlet/Tomat (error symbol not found)?

Tags: java, tomcat

I've been trying to correctly configure the tomcat servlet but seems like I am missing something , after a rather long trial I suceeded in launching the *startup.sh* (**I run Ubuntu**) but already at the *shutdown.sh* I am receiving this error

> /opt/apache-tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/apache-tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
>   /opt/apache-tomcat/bin/catalina.sh: 1: eval: /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/bin/java/bin/java: not found

which I don't know how to fix. This could be the root of the problem , but I am not sure , anyway , I am following a set of instructions at https://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/ (even tho I had to install and configure tomcat from a different source) , when I tried compiling the ***HelloWorld.java*** I got the error , mentioned in the title . (The ***HelloWorld.java*** program is available on the link , and it was copy pasted, so the problem isn't in the code). If someone knows the correct way of configuring tomcat / compiling and running java code on tomcat , please let me know.
**UPDATE**:one of the issues was solved , however I still cannot compile the source containing java servlet code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using eclipse IDE for java then Go to **Windows->show->servers or Windows->show->others->server**, then click on `add server bla bla bla` link under server tab at bottom. There you will see one wizard window that ask for `server name`, `host name`, `runtime env.` and `configuration path`. Fill out all these things and you will be asked to download then click on download, wait it will be automatically downloaded and configured. So simple

Comment: I am using eclipse however I don’t have the server option listed there

Comment: Firstly go to the navigation i have given above then look at bottom of your eclipse window. There you will find console, progress, terminal and server tabs.

Comment: I cannot follow you navicgation sir , I literally don't have server option in any form

Answer (score 0):

This error: /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/bin/java/bin/java: not found
indicates that tomcat is expecting to find your java runtime at this location.

Try setting JRE_HOME to point to the directory where your java runtime is located.
The best place to do this is in setenv.sh as described in the comments in catalina.sh

Comment: Alright I fixed that , thank you for pointing it out , but when I try to compile from terminal it still doesn't recognize the Servlet parts

Comment: Without a complete but minimum verifiable example it's difficult to give you an answer. Assuming that  javac is unable to find the standard Servlet related classes/interfaces that your code relies on, you need to include the needed jar files to your compiler classpath. If you're building with maven, you'd add them as 'dependencies' in your pom.xml file.

In your IDE, when you create a new project, there is probably an option like maven/web. Selecting this will create a pom file with the needed dependencies.